# Ionic 1 + Firebase Authentication

Tags: ionic, firebase

Alguém teria uma dica de tutorial de autenticação com Ionic 1 + Firebase para passar?

Comment: Já experimentou um motor de busca?

Comment: Não achei nada para Ionic 1, só para o ionic 2.

Comment: [1](http://www.arjunsk.com/html5/ionic-loginsignup-using-firebase/) 
 [2](https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/build-a-real-time-hybrid-app-with-ionic-firebase)  [3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1F-0PnLgb8)